# How to provide the same credentials for bitbucket, jira, teams, outlook for an employee?

Tags: outlook, bitbucket, jira, credentials

I got credentials for my outlook, bitbucket, jira and teams at my company and now I’m wondering how it technically works that credentials are the same at all these apps? How the company provide such possibility that I should not create accounts by myself?

Comment: This feature is called single sign-on or SSO. SSO is an authentication scheme that allows a user to log in to multiple sites using a single account, for example using a Google account or Facebook account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my company, and I think in others too, there has simple authorization service that authorize all these apps in the same way.

For example: Active Directory - a lot of applications has integration with this and all these apps authenticates you using only one credential

```
jira -> auth service -> some backend (active directory)
bitbucket (jira) ^
teams etc..      ^
```

I mean, JIRA Bitbucket teams etc. does not save your passwords